# Как правильно сделать авторизацию на php?

Tags: php

Например я хочу чтобы пользователь авторизовался в игре и у него открылась сессия. Если он закроет страницу и зайдет на эту страницу через день, то сессия сохранится? Или это надо делать как-то с куки и базой данных?

Comment: Кики и БД - хороший вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовать сессию можно различными способами, но все они подразумевают сохранение определенных данных для сверки (логины, пароли, токены или другие данные, для валидации и сверки самого пользователя и его текущей сессии, или записи новой при отсутствии оной).

Сохранить эти данные вы можете на свое усмотрение, в cookies, в массиве сессий $_SESSION или в локальном хранилище, называемом localStorage.

Суть будет одна и та же, данные от пользователя, хранящиеся в его браузере вы должны проверить со своими, которые получаете чаще всего из базы данных. Если данные валидны и совпали, сессия живет, пользователь авторизован.

---

Что именно использовать в качестве хранилища на клиенте, решать только вам, при необходимости устанавливать время протухания сессии, а еще и для разных роутов или уровней доступа, чаще всего используют куки, для их установки и отправки реализована специальная функция (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php) в языке.

Однако, глобальный массив $_SESSION, зачастую вызывает у новичков меньше вопросов и приводит к меньшему количеству проблем, т.к. используется он как самый простой массив доступный из любого места в скрипте.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы у вас работала авторизация, вам нужно где-то хранить имя пользователя и пароль (если быть точнее, то хеш пароля). Это может быть текстовый файл, массив с пользователями в каком-нибудь классе или соответствующая таблица в базе данных. И при входе пользователя искать его по логину и сравнивать хеш введённого пароля с тем, который хранится на сервере. Это в общих чертах.

> зайдет на эту страницу через день, то сессия сохранится?

Время жизни сессии настраивается в параметре `gc_maxlifetime` в файле `php.ini`, но, как правило, запоминание пользователя реализуется через cookie, которому можно указать произвольное время, в течение которого cookie будет действительным.

Вообще ваш вопрос довольно общий, поэтому сложно посоветовать что-то конкретное. Смотрите примеры авторизации в интернете и документацию:

- [HTTP cookies](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.cookies.php),
- [работа с сессиями](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php).