# Как сделать что бы сайт запоминал пользователя который вошёл?

Tags: php, mysql

Код регистрации:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","game");
$mysqli->query ("SETNAMES 'utf8'");
$login=$_POST["login"];
$password=$_POST["password"];
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `game`.`users` (`name`, `password`, `money`) VALUES ('$login', '$password', '1000');");
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Код входа:

```
<?php
$login = $_POST["login"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
if($login == false or $password == false){
    echo("Вы не ввели логин или пароль.");
}
$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","game");
if(!$db) exit("Ошибка подключения");
if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.name = '$login'")){
    $rowscount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($rowscount > 0){
        $dbuserdata = $result->fetch_assoc();
        if($dbuserdata["password"] == $password){
            exit("Вы успешно ввошли.");

            exit("Случилась ошибка. Вы ввели пароль неправильно.");
        }
        exit("Пользователя не существует.");
    }
    exit("Не удалось отправить запрос.");
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Как сделать так что бы после входа сайт запоминал человека и ему больше не пришлось входить на других страницах сайта?

Comment: Сессии, куки, больше никак.

Comment: Тебе подойдет. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1083667/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0-php/1083701#1083701

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/hinpDPv Что за проблема?

Comment: @marmid `session_start ()` - должна идти перед любым выводом на экран, чего либо. в самом начале файла, сразу после `<?php` пропиши ее и все.

Comment: Если честно, логика в некоторых местах хромает, при проверке `$dbuserdata["password"] == $password`, `exit("Случилась ошибка. Вы ввели пароль неправильно.");` - этот код не отработает никогда.

Answer (score -1):

[Ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1083701/15479) из похожего вопроса.

Реализовать сессию можно различными способами, но все они подразумевают сохранение определенных данных для сверки (логины, пароли, токены или другие данные, для валидации и сверки самого пользователя и его текущей сессии, или записи новой при отсутствии оной).

Сохранить эти данные вы можете на свое усмотрение, в cookies, в массиве сессий $_SESSION или в локальном хранилище, называемом localStorage.

Суть будет одна и та же, данные от пользователя, хранящиеся в его браузере вы должны проверить со своими, которые получаете чаще всего из базы данных. Если данные валидны и совпали, сессия живет, пользователь авторизован.

Что именно использовать в качестве хранилища на клиенте, решать только вам, при необходимости устанавливать время протухания сессии, а еще и для разных роутов или уровней доступа, чаще всего используют куки, для их установки и отправки реализована специальная функция (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php) в языке.

Однако, глобальный массив $_SESSION, зачастую вызывает у новичков меньше вопросов и приводит к меньшему количеству проблем, т.к. используется он как самый простой массив доступный из любого места в скрипте.